# Python module conflict - Module freezes at the presence of another module

Tags: python, import, module

I am having a strange problem. I have a script that uses **Tensorflow** and a master script that uses **mpi4py**. If I import the Tensorflow script in the master, the Tensorflow program freezes when trying to run a model with no errors. If I run it without importing mpi4py in the master script everything works fine.

Does anyone have any suggestion on what can cause a conflict like this? I always thought a module is isolated from the module that imports it.

Right now, I am residing to running the Tensorflow script in a subprocess but that's pretty hackish.

Any help is greatly appreciated. BTW, I don't have access to the Tensorflow module itself only to the script that's using it and the master script.

Comment: what does your import statement look like

Comment: In the master script I have, `from mpi4py import MPI` and then on the next line: `import siamese` which is the script that uses Tensorflow. Inside siamese.py I have `import tensorflow as tf`